# How do I turn a Start Date column, an End Date column and a column with a Name into running dates and a column with that name for all dates in between

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help in order to turn table A

| DATES | Start_DATE | END_DATE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.20 | 1.1.20 | 3.1.20 | Name1 |
| 2.1.20 |  |  |  |
| 3.1.20 |  |  |  |
| 4.1.20 |  |  |  |
| 5.1.20 | 5.1.20 | 5.1.20 | Name2 |
| 6.1.20 |  |  |  |

into table B using SQL.

| DATES | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.20 | Name1 |
| 2.1.20 | Name1 |
| 3.1.20 | Name1 |
| 4.1.20 |  |
| 5.1.20 | Name2 |
| 6.1.20 |  |

So I want 'NAME' next to all 'DATES' in the range of the 'START_DATE' and 'END_DATE' of 'NAME'

I am completely lost and would appreciate your help!
Thank you

I tried to group the data by START_DATE or by NAME or by END_DATE eg.

```
count(END_Date) over (ORDER BY DATE) AS grp
```

and than use

```
first_value(NAME) over (partition by grp order by DATE)
```

to fill the blanks. Did not work

Comment: Why does your expected result have 4.1.20? why do you want the Name column empty? Why do you have an extra 5.1.20? You can use recursive CTE to produce a daily list but we need to understand the expected result to give you an example script. (You can also use a 'calendar'/'dates' table).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the post. I hope now it is easier to understand my problem, what is the initial situation and what I want to achieve.

Comment: Does Table A have the complete run of dates (no missing dates)?  Also, are there any overlap between the start and end date ranges of different records?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Yes, Table A has no missing dates. But there are some overlaps. The dates represent holidays. It might occur that within a the date range of one holiday there is another holiday.

Comment: I put up an answer, but, in anticipation of a possible question/objection: how do you want to handle the case where holidays have overlapping date ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cross join and then distinct to do this.
Pls refer to below SQL -

```
select 
distinct 
dates,
case when dates between b.Start_DATE and    b.END_DATE then b.NAME else null end as name
from tablea a 
left join ( select distinct Start_DATE, END_DATE,   NAME from tableA) b on 
case when dates between b.Start_DATE and b.END_DATE then 1 else 0 end =1
```

`select distinct Start_DATE,    END_DATE,   NAME from tableA` - This will give you all combination of start,end,name columns.
`case when dates between b.Start_DATE and b.END_DATE then 1 else 0 end =1` - this will ensure you dont have unnecessary cross joins but still some cross join will be there.

I did some R&D with my DB, and here are the output.

[image: my output]

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, you need two data sets (tables, views, or CTEs):

- A list of dates, and
- A list of holiday date ranges

Fortunately, table A is both of those!

Let's do this with a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
WITH Calendar as (
   SELECT a.Dates as CalendarDate
   FROM   TableA a
)
SELECT  c.CalendarDate
        n.Name
FROM    Calendar c
  LEFT JOIN TableA n
    ON  c.CalendarDate between n.StartDate and n.EndDate
```

This won't handle the case where multiple names have overlapping date ranges, but you didn't indicate how you needed that handled.  In the above, if "Name1" and "Name2" had overlapping ranges, you would see a record for each name for each date (from `Calendar`) that overlapped.